# Guardar Archivo Excel ASP c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas Noches quisiera que me ayuden.
Estoy realizando un aplicativo y si me guarda en la ruta correctamente pero cuando quiero ejecutar nuevamente se elimina todo y crea nuevamente .
yo quisiera es que se cree en la misma carpeta así como copia y no se elimine.

```
string query = "SP_ReporteExcel";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion()))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 90000000;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("fechainicio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFinicio.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("fechafin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFFin.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("rubro", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = dprAgencia.SelectedItem.Value;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);

                //Set Name of DataTables.

                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Recibos-Energia Electrica";
                ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Recibos-Agua Potable";

                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {


                    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                    {

                        DateTime d3 = DateTime.Parse(txtFinicio.Text);
                        string Mes = d3.ToString("MMMM");

                        DateTime d4 = DateTime.Parse(txtFinicio.Text);
                        string Anio = d4.ToString("yyyy");

                        wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                        wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        wb.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
                        //wb.Style.Font.FontName = "calibri";
                        //wb.Style.Font.FontSize = 13;
                        wb.Style.Border.DiagonalBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                        wb.Style.Border.RightBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                        wb.Style.Border.LeftBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                        wb.Style.Border.BottomBorderColor = XLColor.Red;

                        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                        ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(1);
                        ws.Cells("A2:H2").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                        ws.Cells("A2:H2").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Yellow;

                        ws.Cells("D1:H1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                        ws.Cells("D1:H1").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Yellow;
                        string datetimeStringFileName = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now);
                        ws.Range("D1:H1").Merge();

                        ws.Range("D1").Value = "Mes de " + Mes + " del " + Anio;
                        //ws.Cells("D1:H1").Value = "Mes";

                        //wb.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                        //wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                    }

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";

                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Reporte_Mensualess.xlsx");

                    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {

                        wb.SaveAs("C:\\DatosSiga\\Logistica\\Reporte_Mensualess.xlsx");
                        //wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                        Response.Redirect("FrmLogeo.aspx");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Imagen Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo debes utilizar una de las dos opciones... no ambas... el Guid o la fecha, comenta una de las dos lineas... var aux y ya debe funcionar :-)

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo cuando subo a un iis hay un problema sale que el archivo esta dañado pero cuando es de mi maquina normal si normal se guarda en disco C: y normal pero el problema cuando subo a un IIS ayudameeeee

Comment: mmmm Que archivo?, puedes poner el error?? exacto... puede ser configuración del iis o de permisos...

Comment: Cámbiale el formato .xls.... tal vez el encoding del excel esta mal....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución rápida es guardar con nombre diferente cada vez, te explico:

```
wb.SaveAs("C:\\DatosSiga\\Logistica\\Reporte_Mensualess.xlsx");
```

En lugar de la linea anterior tienes varias opciones:

A) Utilizar un GUID

```
var aux = Guid.NewGuid()
```

B) Utilizar la fecha y hora actual

```
 DateTime fechaActual = new DateTime.Now;
 CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

var aux = fechaActual .ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm", ci));// formato 201703231842
```

Utilizar alguna de las opciones anteriores y cambiar tu línea por esta:

```
wb.SaveAs("C:\\DatosSiga\\Logistica\\Reporte_Mensualess" + aux + ".xlsx");
```

de este modo se estará guardando un documento diferente cada vez.

Comment: Carrasco cuando lo subo en mi iis si descarga pero sigue descargando en la carpeta descargas pero cuando intento abrir sale este archivo ha sido dañado pero cuando ejecuto en mi maquina local si me logra salir y se guarda en el disco c. ayudameeeeeee

Comment: ayudameeee porfavor

Comment: carrasco me puedes ayudar con esta pregunta.

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58414/exportar-excel-multiple-asp-c