# Exportar Excel multiple asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, aplicación-web

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando una exportacion de un excel pero con un checkbox multiple ya que uno a uno si me exporta pero cuando seleciono dos o mas solo me arroja un excel. ya que no me vota ningun error pero quiero que cuando selecione varios se descargen varios excel segun cuanto yo he selecionado.

este es mi codigo :

```
string message = "";
foreach (ListItem item in lstFruits.Items)
{
  if (item.Selected)
  {
    //message += item.Text + " " + item.Value + "\\n";
    string query = "SP_ReporteExcel";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion()))
    {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
      {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 90000000;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("fechainicio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFinicio.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("fechafin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFFin.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("rubro", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = lstFruits.SelectedItem.Value;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
          cmd.Connection = con;


          sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

          using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
          {
            sda.Fill(ds);

            //Set Name of DataTables.

            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Recibos-Energia Electrica";
            ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Recibos-Agua Potable";



            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {


              foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
              {

                DateTime d3 = DateTime.Parse(txtFinicio.Text);
                string Mes = d3.ToString("MMMM");

                DateTime d4 = DateTime.Parse(txtFinicio.Text);
                string Anio = d4.ToString("yyyy");

                wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                wb.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
                //wb.Style.Font.FontName = "calibri";
                //wb.Style.Font.FontSize = 13;
                wb.Style.Border.DiagonalBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                wb.Style.Border.RightBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                wb.Style.Border.LeftBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                wb.Style.Border.BottomBorderColor = XLColor.Red;

                var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(1);
                ws.Cells("A2:H2").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                ws.Cells("A2:H2").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Yellow;

                ws.Cells("D1:H1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                ws.Cells("D1:H1").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Yellow;
                string datetimeStringFileName = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now);
                ws.Range("D1:H1").Merge();

                ws.Range("D1").Value = "Mes de " + Mes + " del " + Anio;
                //ws.Cells("D1:H1").Value = "Mes";

                //wb.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                //wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

              }



              Response.Clear();
              Response.Buffer = true;
              Response.Charset = "";


              Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
              //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Reporte_Mensualess.xlsx\"");
              Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Reporte_Mensuales.xlsx");


              using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
              {
                //var aux = Guid.NewGuid();
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                //DateTime fechaActual = DateTime.Now;
                //CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                //var aux = fechaActual.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm.fff", ci);// formato 201703231842

                //  wb.SaveAs("C:\\DatosSiga\\Logistica\\Reporte_Mensualess" + aux + ".xlsx");

                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
                Response.Redirect("FrmLogeo.aspx");
              }
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=lstFruits]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
    zip.AddDirectoryByName("Files");
    foreach (ListItem item in lstFruits.Items)
    {
      if (item.Selected)
      {
        string filePath = item.Text;
        zip.AddFile(filePath, "Files");
      }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.End();
  }



  using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {




    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);

    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.Flush();


    Response.End();


  }
```

Comment: Cuando defines la linea string filePath = item.Text; de donde sale el path del archivo? porque recuerda que o los tomas de una carpeta dentro del sitio web o debes hacer un upload a la pagina, no puedes tomar el archivo desde una carpeta de la pc del usuario y trabajarlo directamente

Answer (score 1):

El `Response` solo puede enviar un unico archivo de respuesta, si necesitas enviar varios deberías previamente realizar un `zip` que los una en un solo archivo y enviar este como respuesta de la página.

Dispones de la clase `ZipFile` para poder unir los excel generados

[How to: Compress and Extract Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx)

La idea es implementar como se explica aquí

[Downloading multiple files in ASP.NET](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/286/downloading-multiple-files-in-asp-net)

en el artículo se comprime una carpeta temporal, habria que ver si se puede realiza esto mismo con los archivos en memoria

Comment: entonces primero hago el zip antes del response . lo voy intentar muchas gracias.

Comment: exacto esa es la idea, generas los excel que necesites, los unes en un zip y envias este en el response

Comment: tutini me salio ese error no entiendo porque o porque no tengo C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: que dice el mensaje de error ? ademas porque en Program Files, si estas en un entorno web deberias usar el Server.MapPath() para definir la ruta fisica dentro del sitio web, no uses una carpeta fuera del sitio

Comment: pero en mi codigo no hay ningun server.mappath() edite mi pregunta y al final esta lo que he puesto

Answer (score 0):

No es tan difícil, pero debes entender bien la lógica, primero debes poner todo en una carpeta, estas carpetas se crean en el server, por eso menciona @leandro-tuttini que debes usar carpetas temporales para generar un zip, yo lo he realizado en algunos proyectos no para descargar archivos de Excel, creo que pdfs, como sea de igual manera lo de generar excel ya lo tienes resuelto.

Te explico paso a paso:

1. Cree un nuevo proyecto de ASP.net c#
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. En mi proyecto utilice un nuget Ionic.Zip, para agregarlo:

[Nuget Ionic.zip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Ionic.Zip/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que poner la linea: `Install-Package Unofficial.Ionic.Zip` en la consola de nugget.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate que este seleccionado el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Escribimos `Installa-Package Unofficial.Ionic.Zip` y damos `enter`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se va agregar a las referencias del proyecto la dll

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Agrego los archivos y carpetas de la página web, css, js

[JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js)

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de la página:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EjemploDescargarZip.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br /><br />
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Ejemplo descargar varios archivo en Zip</h3>
         </div> 
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            Haga click en el botón para descargar el zip.
            <button class="btn btn-success">Descargar zip</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Agrego un pluging de jquery para descargar archivos:

[Jquery.FileDownload página oficial](http://johnculviner.com/category/jquery-file-download/)

[jqueyr.fileDownload.js](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js)

Tengo el archivo agregado al proyecto y la referencia en la página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Hay que respetar ese orden

5. En el archivo `default.js` pongo el evento click del botón `btnDescargar`, en donde utilizaremos el plugin jquery.fileDownload

Pruebo el evento del botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para el llamado a la función que genera los archivos y el plugin download es:

```
function DescargarArchivo() {
    //alert("Clic al botón");

    //Genero una lista de documentos a descargar
    var documentos = [];
    documentos.push("Doc1");
    documentos.push("Ejemplo30");
    documentos.push("Nombre generico");
    documentos.push("ArchivoX");
    //-----------------------------------------------------

    //Hago la llamada al server para generar los documentos
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/Descargar",//Este metodo debe existir en la página Default.aspx.cs
        data: "{documentos:" + JSON.stringify(documentos) + "}", //Envio la lista de documentos que voy a generar
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus === "success") {
                var datos = data.d;

                //Muestro mensaje de error en caso de no ser satisfactorio
                if (!datos.Success) {
                    alert(datos.Message);
                    return false;
                }

                //Regreso la ruta del zip, esta ruta será utilizada por jquery.fileDownload para descargarlo
                var ruta = datos.rutaZip;
                $.fileDownload("fileDownload.aspx", { data: { file: ruta } })//llamo a la página fileDownload.aspx
                .done(function () {
                    alert("Documento descargado satisfactoriamente.");
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert("Error al descargar el zip.");
                    return false;
                });
            }
            return true;
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
        }
    });
}
```

6. Tenemos que crear el método `Default.aspx/Descargar`

   ```
   public static Datos Descargar(String[] documentos)
   {

       Datos datos = new Datos();

       try
       {

           datos.rutaZip = Documentos.Obtener(documentos); //Retorno la ruta que es lo que necesito para descargar el archivo
           datos.Message = "";
           datos.Success = true;

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           datos.Message = ex.Message;
           datos.Success = false;
       }
       return datos;
   } public class Datos
   {
       public bool Success { get; set; }
       public string Message { get; set; }
       public string rutaZip { get; set; }
   }
   ```
7. Creo la clase `Documentos.Obtener(documentos);`

   ```
   public class Documentos
       {
           public static string Obtener(String[] documetnos)
           {
               string ruta = "";
               try
               {
                   const string rutaZip = "DocumentosZip";
                   string nombreArchivo = "";
                   const string carpeta = "DocumentosTemp";

                   string nombreArchivoZip = "DocumentosZip" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Trim().Replace("/", "") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                   #region ValidacionDeCarpetas&Archivos

                   List<string> listaArchivos = new List<string>();
                   //Antes de Crear los archivos Elimino todo de la ruta
                   //Elimino de la ruta zip
                   if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaZip)))
                   {
                       //Elimino todos los archivos de la rtua
                       string[] ficherosCarpeta = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaZip));
                       foreach (string ficheroActual in ficherosCarpeta)
                           File.Delete(ficheroActual);
                   }
                   //Elimino de la ruta de los doc
                   if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(carpeta)))
                   {
                       //Elimino todos los archivos de la ruta
                       string[] ficherosCarpeta = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(carpeta));
                       foreach (string ficheroActual in ficherosCarpeta)
                           File.Delete(ficheroActual);
                   }
                   #endregion ValidacionDeCarpetas&Archivos
                   #region ListaDeDocumentosAGenerar
                   foreach (var d in documetnos)
                   {
                       //El nombre que tendrá el archivo
                       nombreArchivo = d + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Trim().Replace("/", "") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";

                       //ruta = EstadoCuenta.EstadoDeCuenta(solCre.Expediente, rutaPdf, nombreArchivoPdf);

                       var nameFile = carpeta + "/" + nombreArchivo;
                       string pathFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(nameFile); //Aqui es donde se mapean los nombres reales del server
                       var directorio = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(carpeta);
                       if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(directorio))
                       {
                           System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directorio);
                       }
                       //agrego el archivo al directorio
                       //Método crear el archivo----
                       CrearArchivo(pathFile);
                       //Esta lista guarda los nombres de archivos generados
                       listaArchivos.Add(nameFile);
                   }
                   #endregion ListaDeDocumentosAGenerar
                   #region GeneracionDelZip
                   if (listaArchivos.Count > 0)
                   {
                       //HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath();
                       if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaZip)))
                       {System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaZip));
                       }
                       //La clase Zipper genera los zips
                       ruta = Zipper.Comprimir(nombreArchivoZip, rutaZip, carpeta);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       throw new Exception("Los archivos no fueron generados");
                   }

                   #endregion GeneracionDelZip
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
               }

               return ruta;
           }
           private static void CrearArchivo(string rutaNombreArchivo)
           {
               try
               {
                   // Example #2: Write one string to a text file.
                   string text = "Texto de ejemplo en el archivo " + rutaNombreArchivo;
                   // WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file,
                   // and then closes the file.    You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
                   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(rutaNombreArchivo, text);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
               }
           }
       }
   ```
8. Crear clase y metodo `Zipper.Comprimir(nombreArchivoZip, rutaZip, carpeta)`

   ```
   public static string Comprimir(string nombreArchivo, string rutaZip, string rutaPdf)
           {
               try
               {
                  var rutaNombreZip = rutaZip + "/" + nombreArchivo + ".zip";
                   using (var zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
                   {                     zip.AddDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaPdf));                        zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaNombreZip));
               }
               return rutaNombreZip;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
           }
       }
   ```
9. Aregar el archivo `fileDownload.aspx`

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                       {

                   var archivo = Request.QueryString["file"];

                   var file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(archivo));

                   Response.Clear();
                   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                   Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                   Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                   Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
                   Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });
                   Response.End();
               }
   ```

**PRUEBAS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por último anexo el archivo con el proyecto de ejemplo:**

[Proyecto de ejemplo - Clic para descargar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6SnlQZXVuZU80NHM)